# finding mean of mixed type CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have the CDF of the form $F(x)=\begin{cases} 0&, x<0 \\ 1-\frac{2}{5}e^{-2x}&, \text{$0 \leq x$} \end{cases}$

Compute $E(X)$. I know $E(X)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x F'(x) dx$ but the number seems tricky.

I get $\int_0^x x \frac{4}{5} e^{-2x} dx$ to get $\frac{-1}{5} e^{-2x}$.
Is it correct?

Comment: $E(X)=\int x dF(x)$ by definition, which in this case is $E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not from $0$ to $x$. It is from $0$ to $\infty$. Otherwise you are on the right path.

Comment: why is it $\infty$?

Comment: $EX$ is a number, it is not  a function. The formula in general is $EX=\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} xf_X(x) dx$.  In this case $f_X(x)=0$ for $x <0$ so the integral is from $0$ to $\infty$. @Beacon